# Laravel 5 join same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, subquery

Hi I need generate two comparations in one table Users, for example i have this table users with different levels

```
   ID       name          email              level
    -------+-------------+------------------+--------------
   34       Jhon Fus       jhon@jhon.com      1 (Medic)
   35       Michael Chi    mich@jhon.com      2 (Client)
```

And this table store the Orders

```
   ID    client_id   medic_id    status   created_at
    ---+-----------+------------+--------+-------
    1    35          34           ok      2015-07-22 19:34:59
    2    35          34           ok      2015-07-23 19:34:59
```

**Expected output**

```
   order id      cliname    status   **medname**   created
    ---------+-------------+--------+------------+-------
    1          Michael Chi   ok        Jhon Fus   2015-07-22 19:34:59
    2          Michael Chi   ok        Jhon Fus   2015-07-23 19:34:59
```

I try this but something is wrong:

```
$orders= Order::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.client_id')
 ->join('users as usmedics', 'usmedics.id', '=', 'orders.medic_id')
 ->select(array('orders.id', 'users.name as cliname', 'orders.status', 'usmedics.name as medname' , 'orders.created_at'))
 ->orderBy('orders.created_at', 'DESC');
```

Any idea please...

Comment: Can join same table with other alias and retrieve column of user table name?

Answer (score 0):

Simple just write a plain query:

```
$sql = "Query as you'd write it normally...";
$result = DB::select( DB::raw($sql));
```

You can still use bindings if needed:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE user_id = :user_id and thing2 = :thing2";
$sqlBindings=[ 'user_id' => $user_id, 'thing2' => $thing2 ];
$result = DB::select( DB::raw($sql), $sqlBindings);
```